# Using varchar(max) in a Stored Proc. Why is the insert value truncated?

Tags: sql-server-2005, enterprise-library

I am new to both SQL 2005 and Enterprise Library (version 4.) I'd like to call a Stored Proc and pass a string that is over 8000 chars. The column in the db is defined as varchar(max). I thought I'd start out by doing a little test first with calling the stored proc from T-SQL and I was surprised that the inserted string value was truncated, even for a short string.

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[ChadTest](
    [TestParam] [varchar](max) NOT NULL
) ON [CMISII_DATA]

GO

ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[spr_ChadTest]
(
 @TestParam varchar(max)
 )
AS
BEGIN
INSERT INTO ChadTest
   (TestParam) VALUES (@TestParam)
END

DECLARE @RC int
DECLARE @TestParam varchar

-- TODO: Set parameter values here.
SET @TestParam = '12345'
EXECUTE @RC = [CMISII].[dbo].[spr_ChadTest] 
   @TestParam

Select TestParam, len(TestParam) from chadtest
```

Output:

```
1           1
```

Once I get this simple example above to work, I will need to figure out how to pass a long string to the SP from VB.NET code using the Enterprise library . What would the data type of the param be? I see no overloaded version of the AddInParameter method that accepts a length nor do I see a "varchar(max)" enum as an available data type.

```
   dbCmd = db.GetStoredProcCommand("spr_ChadTest") 
    db.AddInParameter(dbCmd, "TestParam", SqlDbType.VarChar, TestParam.ToString)
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
DECLARE @TestParam varchar
```

is the problem in your TSQL. You need to declare that as `varchar(max)` datatype to avoid truncation at 1 character length.

Comment: For the ADO.NET part I can't remember exactly. In some cases it uses -1 to indicate `max` but I have a feeling that you don't need to give a length here and it just works it out for itself.

Comment: In straight ADO.NET, there is an overloaded form of the AddParameter method that accepts a length and passing -1 seems like a reasonable approach. Using the Ent Library, I saw no mthod that accepted length, so I ommitted specifying it and passed a string into a varchar param where the string was length 20000. It worked, so I guess I don't need to specify the length. ty!

Answer (score 0):

Your variable definition for `TestParam` is missing the `(MAX)` at the end of it.  This will resolve your SQL query problem.  The following code will add a paramter to a `SqlCommand` allowing the use of `VARCHAR(MAX)` from a VB .Net ASP application.

```
' Set up the output parameter to retrieve the summary.
Dim paramSummary As SqlParameter = New SqlParameter("@TestParam", SqlDbType.VarChar, -1)
command.Parameters.Add(paramSummary)
```

The following [link](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb399384.aspx#Y4809) displays more information